# Copying and pasting a formula into cells of rows that have a drop down tab

Tags: excel, pivot-table

[image: underlying data]

I am working with a public use file, which I downloaded and reformatted into a pivot table:

[image: pivot table]

I am trying to copy and paste the formula from cell D5 into every cell that begins with a US State abbreviation followed by any capital letter (e.g AKAleutians East, AKAleutians West, AKAnchorage, etc.)  from the image I have provided, it looks like these cells appear every third cells; however, further down the spreadsheet, they will sometimes appear every sixth cell, fifth cell, etc. The other thing about this is that the array might shift as well as the number of cells between the drop down menus increase (for example, the array might contain four or five cells).

Is there any way to do this or do I need to reorganize my data in some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Which criteria you use to select the cell to add the value? Which value you want to put in that cell? the biggest? the second?? You just want to add that value, in that cell (in column D)?

Comment: Without knowing what your formula will do/try, why not use this all in the sheet with your Data?  Then you can do a pivot table and have this formula as a row perhaps...Because as you collapse fields in the pivot table, your formulas will get wonky.

Comment: @BruceWayne - first day on this site, thank you for commenting! I believe I will have the same problem if I do what you suggest. The original sheet similarly has varying numbers of health plans per county so it seems like I would just have to do it manually, since the only pattern I can really name is that the first two letter of one of the columns begins with AK (in this case). Does that makes sense?

Comment: Show a picture of the data underlying the pivot table.

Comment: @ElbertV, thank you for taking the time to comment. The criteria I would be going for is the first two letters reoresent US state abbreviations and the third letter can be any capital letter. I am looking for the second lowest cost plan for each county. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have not earned enough points to make my table visible, but it is now attached there. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottCraner, underlying data should be visible now?

Comment: Quick thought - will *all* of your "tabbed rows" start with "AK", or some other known abbreviation? You could use like, `=if(left(A5,2)="AK",[do whatever],[or if false, do this])` perhaps

Comment: @BruceWayne, that definitely worked with all the AK ones, but I have this with a lot of US state abbreviations, and worse than than, there are a different number of arrays that will appear, depending on how many health plans are offered in that county. I realize I may just be asking Excel to be clairvoyant, but this has helped me with one of the states, so thanks for that!

Comment: Well, that's a start! If they *will* start with a state abbreviation, we can load those into an array perhaps, or do a `Vlookup` or something to see if the first two letters of a row start with a state abbreviation, and if so, run the formula.   Do you think that would work?

Comment: @BruceWayne Instead of all fifty states, check if the second letter is capitalized. Then you only need to check the 26 letters of the upper case alphabet.

Comment: Check out [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/X54F3eP.jpg), I got a list of abbreviations from Wikipedia, put them in a column, and used a `Countif` to see if there are any matches, then return "Match" or "Nope".  Ah, with @Scott's comment, I agree, we need to add some logic probably...but does this help get you going?

Comment: @ScottCraner Super, but how do I deal with the varying number of cells that would appear in an array, based on the number of health plans offered in each county?

Comment: I think at this point I need to ask: what exactly are you trying to find? Do not think of the pivot table or anything, what numbers do you want to return?

Comment: I am trying to find the second lowest cost of a health plan in each county, without having to manually retype the formula in each cell. Some counties have two plans. Some have six, so the array would change each time. Thanks.

Comment: @scottcraner also, what is the formula for checking if the second letter is capitalized?

Comment: `=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A5,2,1),{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},""))=0,"True","False")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you!!!

Comment: here is a shorter one `=IF(CODE(UPPER(MID(A5,2,1)))=CODE(MID(A5,2,1)),1,0)`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will try this and hope it works!

Comment: Just make sure there's no typo and you have a second/third/etc. "level" with two capitals in a row. Other than that, nice work @Scott!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of the counties you could easily do a formula and skip the pivot table. So if in your one for one list you had the State in column A and the County in Column B and the Data you showed was on a sheet called DATA then this would do it.

This formula would go in C2

```
=INDEX(DATA!F:F,MATCH(SMALL(IF(DATA!A:A = A2,IF(DATA!B:B = B2,DATA!Z:Z)),2),IF(DATA!A:A = A2,IF(DATA!B:B = B2,DATA!Z:Z)),0))
```

It is an array formula and would need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Then copy down your list.

This would return the second lowest provider based on price.