# how do you find the nth lowest number in an array when numbers repeat themselves?

Tags: arrays, excel

I am trying to find the second lowest cost in this list. Clearly, it is $547, but when I put the formula in: =SMALL(F2:F31, 2) I get $488.00, and I am guessing this is because $488 repeats itself a number of times and so it is the second number in the list of numbers to be the smallest?

What formula should I put in to get the second smallest number, despite repeats?[image: table]

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of this? The end result? Do you seek automation or this is adhoc?

If this is adhoc, you can do:

```
1. copy column with numbers
2. Paste copied column into new sheet
3. Use Remove Duplicates functionality (Data tab) on this column to remove repetitions
4. Use your formula
```

Also, you can do this with one formula :

```
=SMALL(F2:F31, COUNTIF(F2:F31, MIN(F2:F31)) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only want the second smallest number, and you only have 2 digits of significant influence, you can do this fairly effectively without creating additional arrays of data, or using Array Formulas, as long as you can re-order from largest to smallest, instead of smallest to largest.

First, find the smallest number, which is simply:

```
=MIN(F:F)
```

Then, subtract 1 penny from that amount. We can now use price-is-right-rules searching to find the closest number, utilizing the next-best feature of the MATCH function, as follows:

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(MIN(F:F)+0.01,F:F,-1))
```

This will take the smallest number in column F, and add .01 to it. Using -1 as the 3rd argument in the MIN function forces MIN to accept the next best alternative if this amount is not matched exactly.

Comment: thanks for walking through that. I assume that if I have three significant digits of influence I can do this for the second step: =INDEX(F:F,MATCH(MIN(F:F)+1.00,F:F,-1)) is that correct?

Comment: @MelloYellow If you have 3 significant digits, then I would use =INDEX(F:F,MATCH(MIN(F:F)+.001,F:F,-1)).

Answer (score 0):

Only because I figure based on your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685816/copying-and-pasting-a-formula-into-cells-of-rows-that-have-a-drop-down-tab) we are headed this way.  I would as I said in that post make a unique list of all your states and counties.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then building on @Andrew formula, which should be the one marked as correct, with COUNTIFS() as the k value in the SMALL():

```
=SMALL(IF(A2=DATA!A:A,IF(B2=DATA!B:B,DATA!F:F)),COUNTIFS(DATA!A:A,A2,DATA!B:B,B2,DATA!F:F,MIN(IF(A2=DATA!A:A,IF(B2=DATA!B:B,DATA!F:F))))+1)
```

This will give you a clean list of the second value.

Then to find the Insurance company that goes with the quote use:

```
=INDEX(DATA!E:E,MATCH(SMALL(IF(A2=DATA!A:A,IF(B2=DATA!B:B,DATA!F:F)),COUNTIFS(DATA!A:A,A2,DATA!B:B,B2,DATA!F:F,MIN(IF(A2=DATA!A:A,IF(B2=DATA!B:B,DATA!F:F))))+1),IF(A2=DATA!A:A,IF(B2=DATA!B:B,DATA!F:F)),0))
```

Put them in the second row. These are both Array formulas and will need to be confirmed with ctrl-shift-enter.  Then they can be copied down as far as needed.

Comment: Thank you Andrew and @ScottCraner. I wish I knew what these formulas meant or how to come up with them myself...any tips on how to learn the logic here?

Comment: @MelloYellow The best way is to break each one down and use the help on google to understand what each part is doing.  But You should check one as correct.